# Случайные события в Oracle

Tags: oracle, события, sql, java, процедуры

Есть задача: в оракле (11g) реализовать хранимую процедуру, которая выполнялась бы определенное время, и в течение этого времени в случайные моменты выполняла бы некоторое действие. При учете того, что в Oracle я, мягко говоря, новичок, да и с Джавой все непросто, был бы безумно благодарен за хотя бы примерный код.

Comment: вряд ли чтото у тебя получиться =) все сложно =)

Comment: Спасибо за оптимизм. Принципиально я даже могу это представить, как последовательное вычисление случайного значения и задержки на это число миллисекунд, то есть: вычисление случайного-выполнение действия-задержка-вычисление случайного... Но полный швах с реализацией.

Comment: ты поломал мне мосх =(

Comment: Ладно, еще проще: процедура, которая генерирует случайное число, выполняет delay(pause, sleep?) на это число, потом выполняет просто что-то, неважно что.

Comment: ооо всетаки чето шаришь =) а джава тут причем? или ХП можно сделать пару штук, все зашить в джаву, в 2 потока и смотреть на эту кашу?

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса, только что узнал, что внутри Oracle есть JVM и хранимые процедуры можно писать на java.

Из общих соображений, попробуйте Thread.sleep(my_delay_in_milliseconds);

это приостановит выполнение текущего потока. Надо думать процедура исполняется в отдельном потоке, аналогично делается в сервлетах в веб-серверах.

Comment: Дело-то в том, что это как раз единственное, что я знаю... Если не заморачиваться с какими-то более неочевидными реализациями исполнения кода в случайные моменты времени, то этого алгоритма вполне хватит. Может быть, реально и без джавы, не знаю. Но просто я правда совершенный ноль в процедурном программировании в Оракле, именно поэтому мне нужен хотя бы код для процедуры "сгенерировать случайное значение - выполнить задержку", то есть именно код, который вставляешь в Oracle - работает.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://citforum.ru/database/oracle/java_oracle/#14)

Если у Вас проблемы с программированием на java, то для начала почитайте книжки. Без какого-то бэкграунда короткие ответы пользы не принесут.

Comment: @avp, как это интересно, из джавы можно приостановить работу ХП?

Comment: Что такое ХП ?  

Насколько я понимаю, каждый раз при вызове процедуры будет приостановлен поток, исполняющий ее (в рамках SQL запроса). Вызывать .sleep() кажлый раз или нет - наверное зависит от задачи. 

Думаю как-то можно определить в java-программе первый ли это ее вызов при исполнении данного SQL запроса.

Вообще же, все это только догадки. Может быть .sleep() вообще не реализован в этой среде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать реализовать на обычных циклах.

```
LOOP
j:=j+1;
    LOOP
    i:=i+1;
    EXIT WHEN i=random();
    END LOOP
/*некоторое действие*/
EXIT WHEN j=const;  
END LOOP
```

Выполнение цикла занимает определённое время,
внутренний цикл даёт случайную задержку,
во внешнем цикле выполняется *некое действие*.

Comment: Спасибо, но интересует и то, как ее подцепить к ораклу. Потому как то, что я не силшком хорошо знаю и sql, и джаву дает в результате то, что нагугленные примеры представления об этом дали мало. Разберусь-то я в вопросе в любом случае, но без конкретики в данном примере на это уйдет просто уйма времени

Comment: Этот пример без джавы, чистый PL/SQL.   
Для генерации псевдослучайного числа необходим пакет DBMS_RANDOM.
Создаёте процедуру, как объект БД (CREATE PROCEDURE...),
Затем её выполняете (EXECUTE MyProcedureName();).
Если необходимо постоянное(регулярное) выполнение этой процедуры, то следует использовать *cron* на сервере.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: @out, такой подход - это **неправильная вещь**.

Comment: @avp, возможно. Можете пояснить?

Comment: Бездарно жрать ресурсы - это плохо.

Comment: Оптимизация в данном случае - дело десятое. Как и точность. Прекрасно понимаю, что фу писать плохой код когда бы то ни было, но здесь нужно просто самое тривиальное, в лоб, решение реализации случайных событий в реальном времени, дальше уже его можно оптимизировать произвольным образом, но пока нужно просто "сделать как-то"

Comment: Согласен.   
Тогда ещё, как вариант, можно создать процедуру с выполнением только *некоторого действия* и запускать её кроном.    
В начале процедуры добавить рандомно 0 или 1, т.е. выполнять её или нет, при каждом запуске.

Comment: В конечном итоге, несмотря на всю принципиальную некошерность приведенного примера, решил, вдохновляясь им, посему и отмечу, как правильный) Все было сделано в лоб, через dbms_random и dbms_lock.sleep от этого рандома, умноженного на некоторый коэффициент.

Answer (score 0):

АВП, я про то что, остановить ХП(хранимую процедуру) средствами джавы низя, потому что, в джаве ты ее можешь вызвать на выполнение, но выполняться она уже будет в БД и ты только получишь ответ с нее. Для эмуляции задержки, можно задержать вывод результата на экран.
В общем такую псевдо учебную задачу можно сделать быстро средствами Хибернейта.

1. В БД написать ХП, которая например, вставляет новую запись.
2. В джаве вызвать ее
3. Поставить задержку на вывод рельтата
4. Если уж так хочется, пока стоит задержка в другом потоке обратится в БД с какимто селектом
5. Вывести ответ от ХП
6. Ну и конечно везде прицепить рандом =)

Comment: >  потому что, в джаве ты ее можешь вызвать на выполнение, но выполняться она уже будет в БД.

@Gorets, вам @avp толкует о том, что сама хранимая процедура  написана на Java и выполняется внутри БД.

Comment: @Nofate, именно так.

Comment: @Gorets "средствами джавы низя", таки можно уважаемый, если процедура изначально на java... А в данной конкретной задаче проще все-таки сделать средствами самой БД.

Answer (score 0):

если вам надо в оракле то java к этому не имеет никакого отношения.

т.е у вас есть следующие входные данные: `t_start, t_end`. и за это время ваша задача должна генерировать "случайные события". вам нужен **не случайное задание**, назовем его **А**, которое будет регулярно запускатся в момент времени `x_time`, причем должно выполнятся условие `x_time >= t_start`. Его основной задачей будет сгенерировать допустимое количество случайных событий, а так же для каждого случайного события, назовем их **B1, B2, ...**, сгенерировать случайное значение времени выполнения, все значения должны попадать в диапазон `t_end - t_start`.

Далее у вас есть 2 варианта:
1) или вы в самом таске `"А"` делаете паузу скрипта на нужное значение и запускаете задачи B[], с необходимыми задержками (которые легко посчитать используя сгенерированные случайные величины)
2) Вы можете заскедулить все таски `"B*"`

p.s. понятно что вместо таска "А" может быть непосредственный вызов из Java кода который выполняет всю работу по генерации случайных задач. единственное что при вызове с Java кода более логично было бы использовать вариант `1`.

p.s.s. допольнительная информация: гугльме "oracle scheduler" / "oracle manage scheduled tasks"
p.s.s.s. - задача действительно не сложная, если вам для себя имеет смысл разобратся и написать самому. примеров очень много. код действительно травиальный, хотя многое зависит от того что вы подразумеваете под "некоторое действие"